# Could not link driver rlm_sql_mysql

Tags: mysql, freeradius, ppp, l2tp, junos-automation

I have a problem with MySQL:

freeradius -X gives the following command:

```
Could not link driver rlm_sql_mysql: /usr/lib/freeradius/rlm_sql_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Make sure it (and all its dependent libraries!) are in the search path of your system's ld
/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sql[18]: Instantiation failed for module "sql
```

"
admin@ubuntu-de-01:/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available$ freeradius -v

```
radiusd: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Apr 17 2019 at 12:59:55
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
```

The MySQL database is working:

```
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_radius |
+------------------+
| nas              |
| radacct          |
| radcheck         |
| radgroupcheck    |
| radgroupreply    |
| radpostauth      |
| radreply         |
| radusergroup     |
+------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I haven't tried installing libmysqlclient or yum or anything.
This problem started occurring after I've reinstalled the freeradius.

Is there a requirment to reinstall the mysql DB somehow as well?

Thank you

Comment: did you try this guide https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/SQL-HOWTO

Comment: Hi, No I'm using a different method. A guy at our company had this working and so I copied the files over from his directory.
For my version, the SQL config is stored in the mods-available.

Comment: the basis must be the same, i guess that you are missing the radius user, also lok into the mysql error log and see if it shows any problems

Comment: 2020-10-12T07:56:36.576731Z 41 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-10-12T08:29:00.736190Z 45 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

it's only showing the instances I forgot to add the password when logging in. The general syslog file doesn't conaint anything relevant to the SQL DB.
In the mods-available there is the sql.conf file which contains the radius user.

Comment: you can enalbe general log and see what actually reaches the server

Comment: Krisz, you should post your additional information as edits, nobody wants to read comments to get the full story.

Comment: I've added the general log and error log, attached the output as an edit. It doesn't show anything about the user connection attempts.

Comment: When I do a radtest to user_1000 I get (0) No reply from server for ID 164 socket 3

Answer (score 0):

in my case, after downgrading the MySQL version, the `libmysqlclient-dev` library was missed, all that was needed was just to install it.

```
apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Hope, this helps someone.